# Duvida sobre importar bibliotecas

Tags: python, python-2.7

Vamos supor, existe a pasta A.
Nesta pasta A existe a pasta lib.
Nessa pasta lib, existe uma biblioteca chamado exemplo.py.

**Como faço parar importar o exemplo.py?**
Eu vejo que é possível importar da pasta.
Quando eu tento, ele procura na pasta do python.

**Como faço para importar um biblioteca que não seja uma pasta onde o python foi instalado.**

Comment: E qual o nivel do arquivo que você quer importar o exemplo.py?

Comment: Seria uma biblioteca exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acessar a o exemplo.py basta fazer o seguinte. Para um exemplo bem mais detalhado eu coloquei uma função dentro do exemplo.py.

Códigos:

exemplo.py

```
def funciona():
    print("tudo OK")
```

arquivo que vai fazer a importação ex:
main.py

```
import a.lib.exemplo as exemplo
exemplo.funciona()
```

> Nota:
>
> • A keyword "as" é usada para que você não fique tendo que escrever sempre o caminho da biblioteca.
>
> • O resultado do código deverá ser "tudo OK".

Answer (score 1):

Se você colocar o arquivo `__init__.py` nas pastas que quer navegar, o Python vai interpretar como pacotes. Veja:

```
app.py
a/
-- __init__.py
-- lib/
----- __init__.py
----- exemplo.py
```

Assumindo você queira acessar o `exemplo.py` através do `app.py`, você poderia utilizar:

```
from a.lib.exemplo import minha_funcao
```

[Veja mais na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)